# when i try to echo $10 it becomes echo $1 0

Tags: bash, echo

given something like this

```
find -type f -newermt "2011-05-26 15:40:35.088712" | xargs -n 1 bash -c fn=$0; set -- `ls -l $fn`; echo $7 $8 $9 $10;
```

I expect it to output the content in $10
when i try to echo $10 what really happens is it echos $1 along with 0, how do i make it echo $(10)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to use `echo ${10}` to make that work.